# Why am I getting a linker error when using this basic inheritance setup?

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is probably a quite simple question, but I don't how to solve it. I have the following setup of my C++ classes:

**MappingTechnique.h**

```
struct MappingTechnique {
    virtual void processFrame();
};

struct SimpleGreedyMappingTechnique : MappingTechnique {
    void processFrame();
};
```

**MappingTechnique.cpp**

```
#include "MappingTechnique.h"

void SimpleGreedyMappingTechnique::processFrame() {

}
```

Yet, when I build (using `CMake`) I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable PayloadRegionMapper
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for MappingTechnique", referenced from:
      typeinfo for SimpleGreedyMappingTechnique in MappingTechnique.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [PayloadRegionMapper] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PayloadRegionMapper.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PayloadRegionMapper.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [PayloadRegionMapper] Error 2
```

I don't get what's the problem here? Why can't I implement the `virtual` method of the superclass in the subclass? Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: You haven't declared `MappingTechnique::processFrame()` as pure virtual, nor have you given it a definition.

Comment: Thanks @Sneftel! I figured it out thanks to your comment :) I posted my answer, but if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution myself thanks to @Sneftel's comment noting that I didn't declare it as *pure* virtual nor did I give it a definition.

After googling what that means, I came up with the following options:

**Giving it a definition:**

```
struct MappingTechnique {
    virtual void processFrame() {};
};
```

**Making it pure:**

```
struct MappingTechnique {
    virtual void processFrame() = 0;
};
```

I decided for making it pure, only thing to take care of then is that when the abstract class is used (and it is not yet know what actual subclass it will be initialized with), you need to use:

`MappingTechnique *mappingTechnique` instead of `MappingTechnique mappingTechnique`

(which is logical when you think about it but might not be that obvious to a C++ novice). Thanks to @Sneftel!

Comment: Defining virtual functions in a header puts an out-of-line copy of it in each translation unit, making your object files and debug info bigger. Make it either pure virtual or define out-of-line (in a .cpp file).